# Restricting users to specific domains in Postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I have a user list and domain list. All users in `user_list` should only be able to send mail to domains listed in `allow_urls`.

user_list

```
/^user1@*/   OK
/^user2@*/   OK
/^user3@*/   OK
/.*@*/ REJECT 5.4.3. Sorry..
```

allow_urls

```
domain1.ru limited_class
domain2.ru limited_class
```

I have these lists defined in my main.cf, but it doesn't appear to be working. Any user can send to any domain.

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = limited_class
limited_class = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/border/user_list, reject
smtpd_sender_restrictions =  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/border/allow_urls
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You did nothing wrong. The restrictions you configured is for **incoming** mail, where incoming means sent from "outside".

When you now say "every user can send..." then this is true. You can't restrict the destination address when sending to the **outside** world.

If this doesn't answer your question, then please rework on your question to express what you really mean. Or better: What do you want to achieve? You only say that it doesn't work without specifying *what*.

Answer (score -2):

Right solution below

user_list

```
/^user1@*/   limited_class
/^user2@*/   limited_class
/^user3@*/   limited_class
/.*@*/ REJECT 5.4.3. Sorry..
```

allow_urls

```
domain1.ru OK
domain2.ru OK
```

main.cf

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = limited_class
limited_class =  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/border/allow_urls reject
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/border/user_list
```